# Get public page's fans count but not the Global page fans

Tags: facebook, api, public

Since the latest changes of Facebook, is there a way to get the fans of a public page which is part of a global page too? What I mean is that currently the FB API fans_count returns the Global Page's fans and not the local one.

I am trying to get this using FB api, but I would like to see if there other solutions too.

Thank you guys in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you add an example of a page you are currently calling against, the value you are seeing, and the value you are looking to retrieve instead?

Comment: Thank you Patrick for your reply. I was checking to get the fans of https://www.facebook.com/cocacolaromania/ but I always get the same number with the Global Coca Cola page.

Comment: It's documented to works this way. Page insights might be able to get you more info - but only for pages you have admin access to, since this needs a page access token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/insights

Comment: Its strange, there is a field "country_page_likes" which in theory, should provide a value close to what you are looking for "If this is a Page in a Global Pages hierarchy, the number of people who are being directed to this Page." however this field does not seem to return a value. If this is by design and not a bug, then CBroe is right that you'd prob need to go down the page/insights route

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not trying to answer the question. I'm just commenting (I don't have the reputation needed to comment in the oficial way).

As Patrick Lambe says, I can query the "country_page_likes" and I get a number close to the likes of the country I'm currently querying from but, I don't know if this is what is really happening o if there is a way to specify the country to query for.

Has anyone had any luck in this?

Comment: Unfortunately, if the page you check is part of a global page, then you will get the fans of the global page on this metric.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'country_page_likes' via API you should be able to capture likes for all child pages. Try and refresh the access token. Works for me for almost 2 years!